# Connective preposition or subordinate conjunction?

Tags: prepositions, difference, conjunctions, ambiguity, subordinate-clauses

I know that a Subordinating Conjunction or a subordinator serves as a marker for the Subordinate Clause :

> Other children are annoyed because John raises his hand constantly.

Here 'because John raises his hand constantly' is a Subordinate Clause, and 'because' is a Subordinating Conjunction.

But an online grammar website says : here *'because' is a connective preposition.*

Could you please clarify what connective preposition is and whether *because* is a **Subordinating Conjunction** or **a connective preposition?**

Comment: You seem to be causing a lot of confusion with your questions. The fact is that in trad grammar "because" is classified as a subordinating conjunction, but some grammarians (including me) and one or two dictionaries classify it as a preposition. See here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/because)

Comment: Note also that for those who classify "because" as a preposition, the expression "John raises his hand constantly" is still a subordinate clause where it functions as complement of "becuase" Not all subordinate clauses have an internal marker of subordination. "John raises his hand" is shown to be subordinate by virtue of its function in the larger construction.